# How to convert ImageCodecInfo to byte[] or Stream

Tags: c#, image, optimization

I want to upload an optimized images to Amazon.

So that I have found this [article](http://csharphelper.com/blog/2014/07/optimize-jpeg-compression-levels-and-file-sizes-in-c/) that explains how to optimize an image with a compression level.

The problem is that this example saves the image to disk and I need to save it to Amazon storage.

I have this code:

```
public static ImageCodecInfo OptimizeImage(Image image, string fileName, long compression, string type)
{
    var encoderParams = new EncoderParameters(1)
    {
        Param = {[0] = new EncoderParameter(Encoder.Quality, compression)}
    };

    return GetEncoderInfo(type);
}

private static ImageCodecInfo GetEncoderInfo(string mime_type)
{
    ImageCodecInfo[] encoders = ImageCodecInfo.GetImageEncoders();

    for (int i = 0; i <= encoders.Length; i++)
    {
        if (encoders[i].MimeType == mime_type)
            return encoders[i];
    }

    return null;
}
```

I should have a `Stream` or `byte[]` object in order to send it to the `UploadImageToAmazon` method as parameter.

So, I have an Image object and its ImageCodecInfo, how can I convert it to `Stream` or to `byte[]`?

Or if you could suggest me how to optimize images and upload them into amazon would be also good.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can save an Image object to a Stream with [Image.Save Method (Stream, ImageFormat)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142148%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Edit :

If I recap with the code provided in the example you linked:

```
private void SaveJpg(Image image, string file_name, long compression)
{
    try
    {
        EncoderParameters encoder_params = new EncoderParameters(1);
        encoder_params.Param[0] = new EncoderParameter(
            System.Drawing.Imaging.Encoder.Quality, compression);

        ImageCodecInfo image_codec_info =
            GetEncoderInfo("image/jpeg");
        File.Delete(file_name);
        using(var imageStream = new Stream()){
            // save to stream
            image.Save(imageStream, image_codec_info, encoder_params);
            // upload
            UploadImageToAmazon(imageStream);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Error saving file '" + file_name +
            "'\nTry a different file name.\n" + ex.Message,
            "Save Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK,
            MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }
}
```

Comment: @Misha, take a look at the `image.Save` line in your linked article.  Instead of passing a filename as the first parameter, you can use a `MemoryStream`.

Comment: @David I can't use the Save method because I want to save it to Amazon and not local. Or am I missing something? Can I use this method to save directly the images to Amazon?

Comment: @Misha, you will use the regular `Save` method to save to a `MemoryStream`.  By using a `MemoryStream`, nothing will be saved to disk.  Then you can use the `ToArray` method on the `MemoryStream` to get the data you want to upload to Amazon.